# ScalaTestWithActorTestKit not found

Tags: intellij-idea, akka, intellij-scala

Added following in sbt:

> "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % "2.6.3" % Test

Still ScalaTestWithActorTestKit is not detected?

Edit: It seems its more of intellij issue.

Comment: That is part of that dependency, got a reproducer project?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reproducer project'?

Comment: A project e.g. build.sbt, that  adds the dependency and can't compile using ScalaTestWithActorTestkit

Comment: Project compiles with no error.

Comment: Then what do you mean by is not detected? If your project compiles using it, it is detected.